# How Can I create custom og type and .setActionType() while sharing to facebook?

Tags: android, fbsdksharedialog

I have a following code which shares content to FB. How can I create custom `og.type` and `.setActionType`.

```
ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
        .putString("og:type", "Tor")
        .putString("og:title", tour.getTitle())
        .putString("og:description", tour.getDescription())
        .build();

// Create an action
ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
        .setActionType("tour.post")
        .putObject("Tour", object)
        .build();

// Create the content
ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
        .setPreviewPropertyName("Tour")
        .setAction(action)
        .build();

ShareDialog.show(TourActivity.this, content);
```

Example: If I add it with `"og.type"` value to `"books.book"` and `.setActionType` value to `books.read` then it shows in FB shared content that "Is reading book".(**I do not want to display anything else except content I added. It should only display TourName and Description and heading Tour:**).

Comment: @Kling Klang Why I am not getting answer from anybody? Any answer or suggestions?

Comment: ... give them time? Sometimes people will answer one or two days ago. But the best answer could come 5 years later. Not everyone who can answer your question lives in your timezone. Or maybe they do not even know about StackOverflow, yet. Be patient. Meanwhile, research, study, try, do.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like that feature has been deprecated in 2017:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/custom-open-graph-deprecation

> There are two options to replace Custom Open Graph stories:
>
> 1. [Use built-in Open Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph) actions, including the new games.plays, which posts only to people's activity log, and books.rates.
> 2. Or use standard link, quote, photo, video, or multi-media share.